# How to sort array of numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array using this function findMinimumIndex in a for loop, but I can't seem find where it's not sorting correctly. Any suggestions? The function itself works fine, but when I try to use it in a loop, it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
int findMinimumIndex(A[], int a, int b); //Finds smallest index of portion of array (A[i] ... A[j])

int main(){
    int A[5] = {4,6,7,4,3};
    int smallest_index;
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
        smallest_index = findMinimumIndex(A, j, 4);
        printf("Sorted: %d\n", A[smallest_index]);
    }
}

int findMinimumIndex(int A[], int a, int b){
    int smallest_value = A[a];
    int index = 0;
    for (int k = a; k < j - 1; k++){
        if (A[k + 1] < smallest_value){
        smallest_value = A[k+1];
        index = k + 1;
        }
    }
    return index;

}
```

Comment: it doesn't compile! what is 'count' in the `main()`? What is `j` in the `findMinimumIndex`???

Comment: Whoops sorry! Forgot to include some variables! Thanks!

Comment: I see that I'm initializing smallest_value to always be the first index of the "new" array, how can I get past this?

Comment: You get past it by not doing it. You are explicitly asking for that behaviour.

Comment: Just use `qsort()`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find the minimum value and its index, you should switch values:

Look at this example:

You have got array:

```
{4,6,7,4,3}
```

At first, you will find value `3` at index `4`, but you have to move the smallest value (switch with value on `j=0` index):

```
{3,6,7,4,4}
```

Then you will find `4` on index `3`, then, switch it with `j=1`:

```
{3,4,7,6,4}
```

etc.

Modification of your code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
    smallest_index = findMinimumIndex(A, j, 4);
    int tmp = A[smallest_index];
    A[smallest_index] = A[j];
    A[j] = tmp;
    printf("Sorted: %d\n", A[j]);
}
```

EDIT: correction:

length of the array is 5:

```
    smallest_index = findMinimumIndex(A, j, 5);
```

and index should be set to `a`

```
int findMinimumIndex(int A[], int a, int b){
    int smallest_value = A[a];
    int index = a;
    /*  code */
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to call the function findMinimumIndex multiple times to sort the array?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as your code, an only thing is to switch values. @programmer2222

Comment: It doesn't seem to be outputting the correct result.